# Ember CLI throwing "unexpected token" for Jquery script

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm writing a script to change the header after scrolling a certain number of pixels

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({  
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var value = $(this).scrollTop();
        if ( value > 49 )
            $("#header-scroll").css({"height": "50px", "opacity": "1"});
        else
            $("#header-scroll").css({"height": "0px"});
    });
});
```

Ember CLI is throwing this error:

> SyntaxError: keyphrame/components/header-view.js: Unexpected token (4:11)

I've just started playing with Ember, so any advice or suggestions are more than welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not put that in there.

There is [didInsertElement](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#event_didInsertElement) hook. It's called when the component inserted in DOM.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var value = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (value > 49)
        $("#header-scroll").css({
          "height": "50px",
          "opacity": "1"
        });
      else
        $("#header-scroll").css({
          "height": "0px"
        });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Woo! That's the ticket. Could you delve a little deeper into the use of didInsertElement, as well as this._super(...arguments)?

Comment: @jakeinbake `didInsertElement` is a hook in component lifecycle. It is called once when the component inserted into the DOM. `this._super(...arguments);` is a best practice for overrding any methods. It denotes calling parent `didInsertElement`. Maybe you inherit another component and that line calls parent's